# How do I add CacheableMetadata to an array I'm returning in a rest resource?

Tags: caching, 8

I'm getting the following error, which I've seen in several other questions, but as yet I haven't been able to make any of the example solutions work:

> LogicException: "The controller result claims to be providing relevant
>   cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you
>   are not rendering content too early.

Most of the other questions seem to revolve around somebody trying to return a node object, or a URL object, which needs to be added to the response as a cacheable dependency. In my case, I'm just extracting some data from fields and building a simple array with it. But it appears that as soon as I execute a query, the problem rears its head, even if I don't actually use any data from the query:

```
/**
 * Provides a resource for listing available foo data
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "foos",
 *   label = @Translation("Foos list"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/v1/foos",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class FooListResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * Responds to resource GET requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get() {
    $data = [
      'data' => $this->get_valid_years(),
      '#cache' => [
        'contexts' => [
          'url',
        ],
      ],
    ];
    $response = new ResourceResponse($data);
    $response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($data));
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * Get the nodes and list years
   */
  private function get_valid_years() {
    $years = ['2018', '2019'];
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('type', 'foo_type');
    $nids = $query->execute();
    return $years;
  }

}
```

I've also tried this with CacheableJsonResponse, with no better luck. I feel I'm missing something incredibly obvious here. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: yes, this is caused by the query, skip the access check to avoid leaking metadata, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251864/logicexception-the-controller-result-claims-to-be-providing-relevant-cache-meta

Comment: Thank you -- that does the trick. Is the idea here that because you're controlling access to the resource itself, there's no need to check access on the query?

Comment: No, you can control access, either run the query inside of a render context and add the resulting metadata to the response, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245715/how-to-get-cache-metadata-from-nested-render-array-when-returning-response/245724#245724 or run the access check on each entity, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226286/updating-cached-rest-resources. In this case you get an object which provides cacheable metadata. It would be nice if the query would do the same, see the feature request https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2876258